# Where to find a belt for my REVOX B77 MKII reel 2 reel?

Tags: audio

I am totally conscious that this is an Electrical Engineering forum, but I would welcome any input on where to ask for this request.

Please take a look at the pic below :

[image]

The belt whom dead parts you see on the pic in black is used to move the 0000 counter.

The problem is that I don't know at all where to attach theother side of the belt ! Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Funnily enough, if you google `Revox B77 spare belt` you will find several useful answers including a page titled "Replacement counter drive  belt kit"

Comment: Indeed, that's funny, because there are several belts in a B77, and many models of B77 (MKII, several speeds). Also, when looking for vintage spare parts, many answers dates back to 10  years, with most links/shops being stopped... Thus this request to StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, do you need to know where to find a new belt (title) or where to place the new belt (text) or both ;-)

Anyway, i have here a (swiss) german service manual for a REVOX A77, perhaps some informations from there can help you. The manual is some 30+ years old. The visible parts of your photo correspond good to the graphics in the manual.

The (german?) order number for the A77 belt is: '31. 99.0106'

Under the right bobbin board you should find something that i would translate as breaking roller. According to the graphics there should be a pulley integrated in this roller. This should be the place to attach the other end of the belt.